# TYPO3 6.1.11 login front end user programmatically

Tags: php, authentication, typo3

I have made a TYPO3 site with the standard login system, but I want to implement a Facebook login and use Facebook's Javascript SDK.

So far I have implemented this Facebook JavaScript SDK and can log in and get an email that I use to find TYPO3 user in the database (in the table fe_user), and so want to log this user in through php, how do I do it?

Rasmus

Answer (score 1):

You would write a [TYPO3 authentication service](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_sv_1_1_authentication_service.html) for that, or use an existing one. The extension [dix_easylogin](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dix_easylogin) comes to mind. I have not extensively tested it, but I strongly consider using it in one of my projects.